# Python Process share global Numpy Array

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, global-variables

> Hey, I want to share a global NumpyArray(cameraImg) between my main
> programm and the process which runs parallel. But it doesn't work. It says
> "**TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**"
> The main Programm displa_camera() runs in a While Loop, and gets the Image of the Webcam. The img is saved in global cameraImg and used in recognize_faces() to identifiy the face depcit in the Image. It saves the name, which is added to the Image, above the Persons head. Hope you can help me, thx

```
import time, os, cv2 as cv2, face_recognition
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Value
global name
name=""

window_name = 'facerecognition'
def display_camera():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3, 640)  # set Width
    cap.set(4, 480)  # set Height
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
    global cameraImg, name
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        cameraImg=Array('d',img)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.2,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(20, 20)
        )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36, 255, 12), 1)
        cv2.putText(img, name, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (36, 255, 12), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    cv2.imshow('video', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:  # press 'ESC' to quit
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def recognize_Faces():
    global cameraImg, name
    folder_dir = "../images/"
    image_List=[]
    for images in os.listdir(folder_dir):

    # check if the image ends with png or jpg or jpeg
    if (images.endswith(".png") or images.endswith(".jpg") \
            or images.endswith(".jpeg")):
        # display
        image_List.append(images)
while True:
    try:
        newFaces=False
        for path in image_List :
            rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(cameraImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_img)

            img2 = cv2.imread("../images/"+path)
            rgb_img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img_encoding2 = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_img2)[0]

            result = face_recognition.compare_faces(img_encoding, img_encoding2)
            print("Result: ", result)
            if(result[0]):
                newFaces=True
                name= os.path.basename("../images/"+path).split('.')[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


    if(newFaces==False):
        name=""

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:  # press 'ESC' to quit
        break
    time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    secondaryThread = Process(target=recognize_Faces)
    secondaryThread.start()
    display_camera()
```

Comment: `NumpyArray`??? Do you mean `multiprocessing.Array`?

Comment: When you have two processes, each one has its own global variables. In the main process when you assign something to global `cameraImg`, the global `cameraImg` that is in the child process is *not* updated.

Comment: You are also assigning in your main process something to `cameraImg` repeatedly. Even if this was the same global variable for a child process, how is the child process supposed to process each image if you are not synchronizing with the child process, i.e. you may be updating `cameraImg` faster than the child process can process each image. You also seem to be assigning repeatedly to `faces` and `img` in the main process loop but at the end of the loop you would only be processing the last of these values set.